# Binding multiple TreeViews to the same ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

I'm trying to bind multiple TreeViews to the same ItemSource which contains TreeViewItems. Whenever I do this, the last one to load is the only one that displays the items. (So if I have three treeviews declared in a specific order, the last one declared will be the only one to display the items.)

This is a sample WPF project with default settings I created to show it:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TreeView x:Name="TreeOne" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="238"/>
        <TreeView x:Name="TreeTwo" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind: (I'm using MVVM in the real project but this has the same bug)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            TreeItems = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem>() { new TreeViewItem() { Header = "First item" } };
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem> TreeItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[picture of the output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDQHI.png)

If I comment out the second tree, the first one will display properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeViewItem`s are controls and cannot be displayed simultaneously in multiple visual trees (not the same thing as TreeView!). To fix the issue use string collection (`new ObservableCollection<string> { "First item" };`). In case when you have a complex data-objectsuse templating feature for their visualization, e.g:

```
TreeItems = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>() 
{ 
  new DateTime(2017, 1, 1), 
  new DateTime(2017, 12, 31) 
};
```

xaml

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DateItem">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Year}"/>
            <Border Background="Green" Width="2" Height="2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Month}"/>
            <Border Background="Green" Width="2" Height="2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Day}"/>
        </StackPanel>            
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<TreeView x:Name="TreeOne" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DateItem}"/>
<TreeView x:Name="TreeTwo" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DateItem}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely the correct answer. Unfortunately my primary complex data object extends a control, which in retrospect was a bad decision, but it's deeply ingrained now. I think I'll have to patch this quickly by duplicating code to make it apply the same modifications to each tree with a separate data source. :(